# In WPF, how can I animate the width of a Window?

Tags: wpf, animation

As the title says, how should I go about animating the height or width of a Window?  I can do something like:

```
var wdw = new Window();
var ani = new DoubleAnimation(wdw.Width + 150, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2));
wdw.Show();
wdw.BeginAnimation(SomeDependencyProperty, ani)
```

...but Width doesn't seem to be a dependency property.  Am I missing something?  Is there a correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried binding to WidthProperty and ActualWidthProperty.  The latter gives m a "...the IsAnimationProhibited flag has been set on the UIPropertyMetadata used to associate the property with the class." ArgumentException

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my problem was that I was doing a wdw.ShowDialog() (which my example didn't have)